# Can we restore the backup of SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2019?

Tags: sql-server, backup

Is it possible that we can restore a backup made with SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2019?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried this as we mostly keep our system up to date but as per [Offical MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/supported-version-and-edition-upgrades-2019?view=sql-server-ver15#migrate-to-sql-server-2019)

> Backup and restore. A backup taken on SQL Server 2008 (10.0.x) and
> later, can be restored to SQL Server 2019 (15.x) without changing its
> compatibility level, as long as the database backup has a
> compatibility level of 100 or higher.

EDIT:OK just confirmed internally that you can restore from SQL Server 2005 directly to SQL Server 2019 and SQL Server 2022, so restoring from SQL Server 2008 to 2019 should be possible. The problem comes when there is SQL Server 2000 then you would have to restore it to 2005 or later and then move to 2019 version.